# Issues with Gunicon and Docker alpine-fat Image

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn, alpine-linux

I'm having a strange issue regarding Gunicorn installation for a Django project.

My `Dockerfile` extends `FROM openresty/openresty:alpine-fat` as follows:

```
FROM openresty/openresty:alpine-fat

# VERSIONS
ENV ALPINE_VERSION=3.8 \
    PYTHON_VERSION=3.8.0

# PATHS
ENV PYTHON_PATH=/usr/local/bin/ \
    PATH="/usr/local/lib/python$PYTHON_VERSION/bin/:/usr/local/lib/pyenv/versions/$PYTHON_VERSION/bin:${PATH}" \
    # These are always installed.
    #   * dumb-init: a proper init system for containers, to reap zombie children
    #   * musl: standard C library
    #   * lib6-compat: compatibility libraries for glibc
    #   * linux-headers: commonly needed, and an unusual package name from Alpine.
    #   * build-base: used so we include the basic development packages (gcc)
    #   * bash: so we can access /bin/bash
    #   * git: to ease up clones of repos
    #   * ca-certificates: for SSL verification during Pip and easy_install
    PACKAGES="\
      dumb-init \
      musl \
      libc6-compat \
      linux-headers \
      build-base \
      bash \
      git \
      ca-certificates \
      libssl1.0 \
      libffi-dev \
      tzdata \
      postgresql \
      postgresql-dev \
    " \
    # PACKAGES needed to built python
    PYTHON_BUILD_PACKAGES="\
      bzip2-dev \
      coreutils \
      dpkg-dev dpkg \
      expat-dev \
      findutils \
      gcc \
      gdbm-dev \
      libc-dev \
      libffi-dev \
      libnsl-dev \
      libtirpc-dev \
      linux-headers \
      make \
      ncurses-dev \
      libressl-dev \
      pax-utils \
      readline-dev \
      sqlite-dev \
      tcl-dev \
      tk \
      tk-dev \
      util-linux-dev \
      xz-dev \
      zlib-dev \
      git \
    "

RUN set -ex ;\
    # find MAJOR and MINOR python versions based on $PYTHON_VERSION
    export PYTHON_MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo "${PYTHON_VERSION}" | rev | cut -d"." -f3-  | rev) ;\
    export PYTHON_MINOR_VERSION=$(echo "${PYTHON_VERSION}" | rev | cut -d"." -f2-  | rev) ;\
    # replacing default repositories with edge ones
    echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v$ALPINE_VERSION/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories ;\
    echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v$ALPINE_VERSION/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories ;\
    # Add the packages, with a CDN-breakage fallback if needed
    apk add --no-cache $PACKAGES || \
        (sed -i -e 's/dl-cdn/dl-4/g' /etc/apk/repositories && apk add --no-cache $PACKAGES) ;\
    # Add packages just for the python build process with a CDN-breakage fallback if needed
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PYTHON_BUILD_PACKAGES || \
        (sed -i -e 's/dl-cdn/dl-4/g' /etc/apk/repositories && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PYTHON_BUILD_PACKAGES) ;\
    # turn back the clock -- so hacky!
    echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v$ALPINE_VERSION/main/" > /etc/apk/repositories ;\
    # echo "@community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v$ALPINE_VERSION/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories ;\
    # echo "@testing http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v$ALPINE_VERSION/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories ;\
    # echo "@edge-main http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories ;\
    # use pyenv to download and compile specific python version
    git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv /usr/local/lib/pyenv ;\
    # install
    GNU_ARCH="$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)" ;\
    # flag explanation:
    # --with-shared : python-dev
    PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/lib/pyenv CONFIGURE_OPTS="--build=$GNU_ARCH --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-shared --with-system-expat --with-system-ffi --without-ensurepip --with-shared" /usr/local/lib/pyenv/bin/pyenv install $PYTHON_VERSION ;\
    # keep the needed .so files
    # ignore libpython - that one comes from the pyenv instalation
    find /usr/local -type f -executable -not \( -name '*tkinter*' \) -exec scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' '{}' ';' \
        | tr ',' '\n' \
        | sort -u \
        | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
        | grep -ve 'libpython' \
        | xargs -rt apk add --no-cache --virtual .python-rundeps ;\
        # for debug
        # | xargs -n1 echo ;\
    # delete everything from pyenv except the installed version
    # this throws an error but we ignore it
    find /usr/local/lib/pyenv/ -mindepth 1 -name versions -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} \; || true ;\
    # delete files to to reduce container size
    # tips taken from main python docker repo
    find /usr/local/lib/pyenv/versions/$PYTHON_VERSION/ -depth \( -name '*.pyo' -o -name '*.pyc' -o -name 'test' -o -name 'tests' \) -exec rm -rf '{}' + ;\
    # symlink the binaries
    ln -s /usr/local/lib/pyenv/versions/$PYTHON_VERSION/bin/* $PYTHON_PATH ;\
    # set timezone info
    ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime ;\
    # remove build dependencies and any leftover apk cache
    apk del --no-cache --purge .build-deps ;\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# since we will be "always" mounting the volume, we can set this up
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init"]
CMD ["python"]

# allowed domains should be lua match pattern
ENV DIFFIE_HELLMAN='' \
    ALLOWED_DOMAINS='.*' \
    AUTO_SSL_VERSION='0.13.1' \
    FORCE_HTTPS='true' \
    SITES='' \
    LETSENCRYPT_URL='https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory' \
    RESOLVER_ADDRESS='8.8.8.8'

# APP LEVEL ENV VARIABLES
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED='true'

# Here we install open resty and generate dhparam.pem file.
# You can specify DIFFIE_HELLMAN=true to force regeneration of that file on first run
# also we create fallback ssl keys
RUN apk --no-cache add bash openssl \
    && /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luarocks install lua-resty-auto-ssl $AUTO_SSL_VERSION \
    && openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3650 -nodes -x509 \
    -subj '/CN=sni-support-required-for-valid-ssl' \
    -keyout /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.key \
    -out /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.crt \
    && openssl dhparam -out /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/dhparam.pem 2048 \
    # let's remove default open resty configuration, we'll conditionally add modified version in entrypoint.sh
    && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf conf /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/
COPY resty-entrypoint.sh /resty-entrypoint.sh

VOLUME /etc/resty-auto-ssl

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/resty-entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/resty-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["/usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty", "-g", "daemon off;"]

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/init.sh"]
```

My `requirements.txt` file:

```
certifi==2019.9.11
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.2.6
django-cors-headers==3.1.1
django-filter==2.2.0
django-guardian==2.1.0
djangorestframework==3.10.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
Markdown==3.1.1
psycopg2==2.8.4
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.6
```

The `init.sh` script called at the end of the Dockerfile essentially starts up the Django server using gunicorn:

```
#!/bin/sh
python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py shell < createsuperuser.py

/usr/local/bin/gunicorn app.wsgi:application --timeout 200 -w 2 -b :8000
```

However, the output from this step gives the following:

```
Successfully built cb42cd687209
Successfully tagged ebapps_web:latest
Recreating webapps_web_1 ... done
Attaching to webapps_web_1
web_1  | 
web_1  | 152 static files copied to '/usr/src/app/static'.
web_1  | Operations to perform:
web_1  |   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
web_1  | Running migrations:
web_1  |   No migrations to apply.
web_1  | Superuser creation skipped
web_1  | /usr/src/app/init.sh: line 8: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn: not found
```

I feel like it could be a very simply fix.

I have tried installing py3-gunicorn on top of my `requirements.txt` file - from here: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/py3-gunicorn

This gices the same error as above...

I'm now thinking it could be due to `gunicorn 19.9.0` compatibilities with `Python 3.8`?

Output of all available `sys.paths` gives:

```
/usr/src/app
/usr/local/lib/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python38.zip
/usr/local/lib/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8
/usr/local/lib/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Comment: get a shell into the image and check whether a `gunicorn` binary actually exists in `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn`. I just tried to build from the same image, but installing python from `apk`, and the gunicorn binary is at `/usr/bin/gunicorn`. Maybe because you're installing python in a different way, but it's worth the shot to check where is the binary located, because the error is pretty clear: `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn: not found`

Comment: Of course - I get the error and what have you, but it seems that the `sys.path` I can see isn't there...

Comment: Hmmmm, oddly, changing to `gunicorn app.wsgi:application --timeout 200 -w 2 -b :8000` seems to have worked.

Comment: so the problem was the path after all :P